# Accessing data from Cassandra using java

Tags: java, cassandra, cqlsh

I have multi-lingual text crawled from various websites using `apache nutch` in `Cassandra` database. I have also defined a `Java` class for translation using the `bing` client. But can anyone tell me how to connect to Cassandra and translate the multi-lingual text using the Java class I defined and store it back into Cassandra itself with an appended column?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per question you have already code for translation you need only to connect your Cassandra Data Base.

Have you using any specific java client for Cassandra?

From below link you get all the java client for Cassandra DB.

http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/drivers.html

Comment: Hey, I've already tried using datastax api, but I am not able to take each column data and take it as an argument into a Java class for translation!

Comment: You want single column data. And send me the database details.